# How to use custom fonts on a input placeholder?

Tags: html, css, font-face, placeholder

I am using custom fonts (@font-face), and they show up properly on my entirely application except on input **placeholders**.

The font is not showing up and the placeholder is blank.

The input font (when I type something) is working fine.
Also, if I change the placeholder font for a system font (Arial, Tahoma...) it works too.

How can I use custom fonts for the placeholder?

Input:

```
<input placeholder="Search character" type="text" class="search-character">
```

CSS:

```
body { font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif; }
.search-character::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif;
}
.search-character::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif;
}
.search-character:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif;
}
.search-character:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif;
}
.search-character::placeholder {
  font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the `font-family` property to the [`::placeholder` pseudo-class](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/).

```
input::placeholder
{
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

Also, note that `input` does not inherit `font-family` by default due to user-agent stylesheets; look at this snippet:

```css
body
{
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler;
}

input::placeholder
{
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="hello" />
```

The placeholder is styled, but the text is not.

Comment: @ArturHaddad May I see your code please? Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: @ArturHaddad Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. In Firefox it works and font-family is inheriting from body.

Comment: @ArturHaddad The snippet that I wrote works for me in Chrome 72. Are you using an older version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189489/discussion-between-artur-haddad-and-laptou).

Answer (score 0):

```
input::placeholder { 
 font-family: Arial;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  font-family: Arial;
}

input::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  font-family: Arial;
}
```